# Bash: proper handling of errors

Tags: bash, shell, error-handling

I have bash script similar to:

```
{
  # Try block
  command 1
  command 2
  command 3
} || {
  # Catch errors
  while true; do
  {
    # Try block inside
    # Change parameters for command 1, command 2
    command 1
    command 2
    command 3
    break
  } || {
      # Change parameters and try again
      continue
  }
done
}
```

More or less this code works fine, but...

For some reason `try` sections works not as expected for me. I thought that it fails if some of my commands return not `0` code, but it's not true.

For some specific cases my `command 2` returns `1` code in the first try block, but it doesn't fail and goes into `catch` section, `command 3` executes from this `try` block and that's it.

Here is my question:

How to handle errors in bash? Just to play with return codes?

*UPDATE:*

Original code looks very similar to:
The main idea is that all 3 commands should be executed one-by-one and all of them are somehow related to `folder_name`.

```
folder_name=my_folder
suffix=0
{
  cd /home/test/
  mkdir $folder_name
  ls -la $folder_name
} || {
    while true; do
      suffix=$(expr $suffix + 1)
      {
        folder_name=$folder_name_$suffix
        cd /home/test/
        mkdir $folder_name
        ls -la $folder_name
        break
      } || {
          continue
      }
    done
}
```

Comment: I would recommend implementing this as a script instead of writing a lengthy and less readable one liner. Hope you can understand the reason why.

Comment: @Anubis, I'm trying to wrap this into the script, but it looks awful and works not as I expect..That's why I published this question.

Comment: If you can show a simplified but working code, may be I'll be able to help.

Comment: @Anubism, I've updated original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems here.

When grouping commands using curly braces, there **must** be a semicolon at the end (or a newline before the closing brace). Refer to [docs here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html)

On the other hand, you are not considering return codes anyway. You normally check the return code with something like `[[ $? -eq 0 ]]`. But in here, you can simply chain the commands with `&&`.
e.g.

```
{
  cd /home/test/ && 
  mkdir $folder_name &&
  ls -la $folder_name;
}
```

However, following will do what you need.

```
cd /home/test/
prefix=my_folder                                                                                                                                      
suffix=0

folder_name="$prefix"
while true; do
  if [[ -e $folder_name ]]; then
    folder_name="${prefix}_$((++suffix))"
    continue
  fi  
  mkdir "$folder_name"
  if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "mkdir failed"
    exit 1
  fi  
  break
done
```

Comment: Well, I've replaced my code into `{ command 1 && command 2; echo $?} || { echo "failed"}` and it returns non-zero return code. It can't print `failed` as expected. What is wrong here?

Comment: That's wrong. Braced group's return code is the return code of the last command. In your case `echo $?` executes successfully and returns `0`, which means the group execution was successful. Just remove it and it'll work, `{ comamnd 1 && command 2; } || {echo 'failed'; }`. Don't forget the semicolon (or a newline).

Comment: @Anubis, hmm..interesting. So, it's not possible to `echo` some success message there?

Comment: Yes you can, `{ comamnd 1 && command 2 && echo 'success'; } || {echo 'failed'; }`. Bash proceeds to the next command in an `&&` chain only if the current command returned with `0`. If any failed, the chain will break right there with the failed error code.

Answer (score 1):

As you probably already know, you can use `set -e` (== `set -o errexit`) to simplify error handling by making the script abort on an untested failure.

Unfortunately with it, non-exec'd subshells behave differently than exec-ed shell children, because a non-exec'd subshell can see whether it's tested whereas an exec'd shell child  cannot.

Consequently, this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

echo "EXEC'D SHELL CHILD"
if sh -e <<'EOF'
true(){ echo true; return 0; }
false(){ echo false; return 1; }
true
false 
true
true
EOF
then
    echo SUCCESS
else
    echo FAILED: $?
fi

echo ===========
echo "NON-EXEC'D SUBSHELL"
if (
true(){ echo true; return 0; }
false(){ echo false; return 1; }
true
false 
true
true
)
then
    echo SUCCESS
else
    echo FAILED: $?
fi
```

Outputs:

```
EXEC'D SHELL CHILD
true
false
FAILED: 1
===========
NON-EXEC'D SUBSHELL
true
false
true
true
SUCCESS
```

*(Feel free to use /bin/bash instead of /bin/sh -- it behaves exactly the same)*

So you can use `set -e` to somewhat simplify error handling, but you still need `&&` or `|| return 1` in a tested subshell (or block or function), or you need to use an exec'd shell child instead. In your case, you can do:

```
 sh -ec' command 1
  command 2
  command 3' || ...
```

or

```
 {  comman 1 && command 2 && command 3; } || ...
```

Comment: Currently, I'm using `bash -x` in my script with set `set -o nounset
set -o errexit
set -o pipefail`, that's why I'm not sure how it works together with `-e`.

Comment: `set -o errexit` == `set -e`. They're two ways of turning on the same feature.

Comment: @smart Personally, I'm quite convinced that, although I use it myself, the `errexit` feature is misdesigned. I think the above difference between exec'd shells and subshells/blocks/functions shouldn't exist, but the semantics of `set -e` are already set in stone/POSIX.