# Bash control flow using || on function, with set -e

Tags: bash, function, shell, error-handling

If I put `set -e` in a Bash script, the script will exit on future errors. I'm confused about how this works with functions. Consider the following, which will only print `one` to standard out:

```
set -e # Exit on error
fun(){
    echo one
    non_existing_command
    echo two
}
fun
```

Clearly, the `non_existing_command` is an error and so the script exits before the second `echo`. Usually one can use the *or* operator `||` to run another command if and only if the first command fails. That is, I would suspect the following to print out both `one` and `three`, but not `two`:

```
set -e # Exit on error
fun(){
    echo one
    non_existing_command
    echo two
}
fun || echo three
```

What I get however is `one` and `two`. That is, the `||` operator prevents the exit (as it should) but it chooses to continue with the function body and disregard the right-hand command.

Any explanation?

Comment: Check out https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65532/why-does-set-e-not-work-inside .  TL;DR: The POSIX spec for set -e is basically broken and you have no hope of every making it work with checked functions without incurring runtime  performance penalties or going outside of POSIX confines (and I know of no nonstandard shell functionality that allows set -e to work context-free within a checked context).

Comment: So the solution is to use && or extract the set -e function to a separate script or avoid the checked context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash: proper handling of errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45398613/bash-proper-handling-of-errors)

Comment: Have a look at ["Why doesn't set -e do what I expected?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ#BashFAQ.2F105.Why_doesn.27t_set_-e_.28or_set_-o_errexit.2C_or_trap_ERR.29_do_what_I_expected.3F).  I agree with @PSkocik that `set -e` has serious issues and should generally be avoided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears to be documented in [the `set` builtin command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin)

> If a compound command or shell function executes in a context where `-e` is being ignored [such as on the left-hand of a `||`], **none of the commands executed within the compound command or function body will be affected by the `-e` setting**, even if `-e` is set and a command returns a failure status.

Emphasis and comment are mine.

Also, if you try to `set -e` within the function, don't bother: the next sentence:

> If a compound command or shell function sets `-e` while executing in a context where `-e` is ignored, that setting will not have any effect until the compound command or the command containing the function call completes.